# Mean and Variance of a function of a multivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, transform

I have a multivariate normally-distributed random variable:

$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$

And another RV which is a deterministic elementwise function of this variable (producing another random vector of the same dimensionality):

$Y=f(X)$ .

In my case $f(X) = \max(0, X)$, which truncates negative parts of the distribution for each element of $X$ to $X=0$, so that $p(Y_i=0)=p(X_i<0)$.  But the ideal solution would work for any function.

I'd like to find $\text{E}(Y)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$.  Is there an analytical way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $Z \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $W = \max(0,Z)$. Note that $P(W = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$ so $W$ is like a continuous random variable plus a point mass at 0. This means that the CDF $F_W$ of $W$ is
$$
F_W(w) =
\begin{cases}
0 \hspace{15mm} w < 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} \hspace{14mm} w = 0 \\
\Phi(w) \hspace{8mm} w > 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
with a discontinuity at 0.

We want the pdf of this. Let $\delta_0$ be the probability measure defined by $\delta_0(A) = I(0 \in A)$ where $I$ is the indicator function. Let the Lebesgue measure be $m$.

Consider some measurable set $A \subset \mathbb R$. Note that $(m + \delta_0)(A) = 0 \implies P(W \in A) = 0$ therefore $P_W$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m + \delta_0$. This means we can obtain the Radon-Nikodym pdf $f_W$ of $W$, denoted by
$$
f_W = \frac{\text d P_W}{\text d(m + \delta_0)}.
$$

Once we have this we can compute the expectation as follows:
$$
E(W) = \int_\mathbb R w \,\text dP_W = \int_\mathbb R w f_W(w) \,\text d(m + \delta_0)
$$

$$
=\int_{\{0\}} w f_W(w) \,\text d\delta_0 + \int_{(0, \infty)} w f_W(w) \,\text dm
$$

$$
= 0 + \int_{(0, \infty)} w f_W(w) \,\text dm
$$

Because $F_W(w) = \Phi(w)$ on $(0, \infty)$ we know that $f_W(w) = \phi(w)$ on this interval therefore
$$
E(W) = \int \limits_0^\infty w \phi(w) \,\text dw = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$

We can confirm this via simulation:

```
z <- rnorm(1e5)
w <- sapply(z, function(v) max(c(0,v)))
mean(w)
1 / sqrt(2 * pi)
```

The second moment $E(X^2)$ can be found in a similar fashion. I was not rigorous with much of this, and your particular case is a little more complicated, but I think this shows the overall way to get an analytic solution out of this.

**Update:** $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Let $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then

$$
F_W(w) =
\begin{cases}
0 \hspace{15mm} w < 0 \\
F_X(0) \hspace{6mm} w = 0 \\
F_X(w) \hspace{6mm} w > 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

so we find that
$$
E(W) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int \limits_0^\infty w \exp \left( -\frac{(w - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) \,\text dw.
$$

We can write this in terms of the standard normal CDF $\Phi$: letting $u = \frac{w-\mu}{\sigma}$, we obtain
$$
E(W) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int \limits_0^\infty w \exp \left( -\frac{(w - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) \,\text dw = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \limits_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty (\sigma u + \mu) \exp \left( -u^2/2\right) \,\text du
$$

$$
= \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[ \sigma \int \limits_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty u e^{-u^2/2} \,\text du + \mu \int \limits_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} \,\text du \right].
$$
Substituting $z = u^2/2$ in the left integral we find
$$
E(W) = \frac\sigma{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}} + \frac\mu{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[ \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} \,\text du - \int \limits_{-\infty}^{-\mu/\sigma} e^{-u^2/2} \,\text du\right]
$$

$$
= \frac\sigma{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}} + \mu \left( 1- \Phi(-\mu/\sigma) \right).
$$

This expression still has an integral in it but at least it is a standard integral that we are comfortable with.

In R:

```
x <- rnorm(1e6, mean=2, sd=1.5)
w <- sapply(x, function(v) max(c(0,v)))

## checking CDF
mean(w <= 1)
pnorm(1, 2, 1.5)

## checking expectation
mean(w)

expectation <- function(y, mu, sigma) {
  y * exp(-.5 * (y - mu)^2 / sigma^2) / sqrt(2 * pi) / sigma
}
integrate(expectation, 0, Inf, mu=2, sigma=1.5)

## using simpler expression
E_W <- function(mu, sigma)
  sigma / sqrt(2 * pi) * exp(-.5 * (mu/sigma)^2) + mu * (1 - pnorm(-mu/sigma))
E_W(mu=2, sigma=1.5)
```

**Update 2**

Here's the complete multivariate case. Let $X \sim \mathcal N (\mu, \Sigma)$ and $Y = (Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ for $Y_i = \max(0, X_i)$. What I have done above is sufficient for $E(Y) = (E(Y_1), \dots, E(Y_n))$ so what remains is the variance $\Sigma_Y := Var(Y)$. The diagonal of $\Sigma_Y$ we can do already: it is just $E(Y_i^2) - E(Y_i)^2$ and we have (albeit ugly) expressions for those.

So in order to fill in the rest of $\Sigma_Y$ we need $Cov(Y_i, Y_j) = E(Y_iY_j) - E(Y_i)E(Y_j)$, so the only missing part at this point is $E(Y_iY_j)$.

The CDF of $(Y_i, Y_j)$ has a form analogous to the univariate CDFs so it turns out that
$$
E(Y_i Y_j) = \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^\infty y_1 y_2 f_{X_i, X_j}(y_1, y_2)\,\text dy_1 \,\text dy_2.
$$

Confirming this:

```
library(cubature)
library(mvtnorm)

## generating data
sx = 1; sy = 2; rho = .5
Sigma <- matrix(c(sx^2, sx * sy * rho, sx * sy * rho, sy^2), 2)
mu = c(-1, 2)
x <- MASS::mvrnorm(5e5, mu, Sigma)
y <- t(apply(x, 1, function(v) sapply(v, function(v2) max(c(0,v2)))))

## checking CDF
mean(y[,1] <= .5 & y[,2] <= 1.25)
mean(x[,1] <= .5 & x[,2] <= 1.25)
mvtnorm::pmvnorm(upper=c(.5,1.25), mean=mu, sigma=Sigma)


## checking E(Y_i Y_j)
mean(y[,1] * y[,2])

expectation <- function(vec, mu, sigma){
  prod(vec) * mvtnorm::dmvnorm(vec, mu, sigma)
}
adaptIntegrate(expectation, lowerLimit = c(0,0), upperLimit = c(100, 100), mu=mu, sigma=Sigma)$integral
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't be nearly as nice when $\mu \neq 0$. You lose symmetry which makes it quite a bit sloppier.

Comment: True, but at least this is still a principled approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However, I have trouble seeing how this could be extended to answer the original problem.  The main difficulty would be in solving the integral when (a) $\mu$ is not zero, and (b) $\Sigma$ is not diagonal.

Comment: @Peter I've added a bit on $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma)$. Also note that this does address your general case for $E( \bf Y)$ since the expectation of a random vector is the vector of expectations of each element, and we've got $E(Y_i)$ for each $i$.

Comment: @Peter I believe that I've completed extended this to the multivariate case at this point.

Comment: Thanks @Chaconne, will get back to this and mark to either mark your response complete or post a simplified solution later.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. I'd be very interested in seeing a simpler solution if it exists.

Comment: There're a bunch of papers on it from the 70's: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165176579901113

Comment: @Peter If I'm reading these correctly it seems that they're answering slightly different things than your question. In the Lee paper that you link to, they're deriving the results for error terms which importantly have mean 0 which makes the math way easier (see the first two sections of my answer, for example). Lee cites Tallis (1961), where Tallis derives the MGF of the truncated normal. I found the first page of this paper (rest was paywalled) and it looks like it is again the mean 0 multivariate normal. I definitely could be wrong about this though

Comment: It does use a zero-mean multivariate normal, but allows for arbitrary cutoffs, so the problem is equivalent to arbitrary-mean with zero-cutoffs.  It's also dealing with a truncated-normal, rather than a rectified-normal (as is the case in my problem), but I think this is a pre-requesite for finding the solution for the rectified-normal case.  ([Non-paywall source](http://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/55008/1/1979-122.pdf))

Comment: Well, let's say we have $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, 1)$ so $$E(\max(X, 0)) \propto \int_0^\infty x e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2} = e^{-\mu^2/2} + \mu \sqrt{2\pi} \left( 1 - \Phi(-\mu)\right).$$ If this integral has a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions of $\mu$ then it looks like we can turn that into a closed-form solution to $\Phi(\mu)$, which is provably impossible. So if this is all correct then the only possible 'closed forms' for $E(\max(X, 0))$ will have special functions in them and aren't very different from expressions with integrals. Does this seem right?

Comment: @Peter I see what you're saying -- if we have a satisfactory solution for $\int_c^\infty x e^{-x^2/2}dx$ then we can also handle $\int_0^\infty x e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2}dx$. My point was that this 'satisfactory solution'  in general necessarily contains special functions such as $\Phi$ or $\text{erf}$ so it's just an integral in disguise. It's just a matter then of manipulating the integrals in my answer into whatever form you like best (also thanks for the non-paywall source).